# Arduino WiFiWebClient does not work

Tags: c, web, arduino

I'm trying to get data from a txt file through my website to turn the LED on or off, the connection to the website works and the data from a txt file is printed on the serial as the code shows, but on the loop condition when I read a txt file with '1' it should light on the LED, but that does not work
can you please help me

this is my code

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

char ssid[] = "HomeBroadband"; //  your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = "h12345678";    // your network password (use for WPA, or use as key for WEP)
int keyIndex = 0;            // your network key Index number (needed only for WEP)

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
// if you don't want to use DNS (and reduce your sketch size)
// use the numeric IP instead of the name for the server:
//IPAddress server(74,125,232,128);  // numeric IP for Google (no DNS)
char server[] = "daffostore.com";    // name address for Google (using DNS)

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
WiFiClient client;

void setup() {
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // check for the presence of the shield:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
    // don't continue:
    while (true);
  }

  String fv = WiFi.firmwareVersion();
  if (fv != "1.1.0") {
    Serial.println("Please upgrade the firmware");
  }

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to wifi");
  printWifiStatus();

  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");
  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, 80)  == 1) {
    Serial.println("connected to server");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET /ard/ledstatus.txt HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: daffostore.com");
    client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
    //client.println("Content-Length: 1845");
    client.println("Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=20");
    client.println();
  }
}

void loop() {
  // if there are incoming bytes available
  // from the server, read them and print them:
  while (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.write(c);

    if(c=='1'){
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      }
      else{
        digitalWrite(13, LOW);
        }


  }



  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting from server.");
    client.stop();

    // do nothing forevermore:
    while (true);
  }
}


void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}
```

Comment: Maybe your loop is to short, I mean that it correctly reads and switch on the LED but the loop+1, that is performed a very little time after, it will switch off the LED due to a '0' char read. Try to put a `delay(1000);` inside your loop.

Comment: you mean that I should put a delay?

Comment: does not solve the problem

Comment: To understand if I'm getting you. The loop works and output c variable through serial line, but the LED is not switched on when c var is '1'. Is it correct?

Comment: Ok, I don't know what to tell you. If your HW is ok, the code of function loop with delay is ok, then the problem is somewhere we could not see from the posted code.